# Failing to import repo in github from one organization to another

Tags: git, github

I am trying to import repo from one organization to another. The size of the repo is 12.5GB with a directory of images of size 4.5GB and a .githistory of 4.5GB. So the import is failing.

Tried cloning into my local machine and pushed it to the newer repo, failing since git documentation says the file size needs to be <2GB and branch size.

Receiving the following error, when pushing it from the local machine.

```
"error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet"
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve it, so that I don’t lose my working branches, and tracking history

Comment: That is an exceedingly large GitHub repo. Generally speaking, Git isn’t very good at handling binary files, such as images. You _might_ need to rebase your history to remove the images, and either store them elsewhere, or use Git LFS (which GitHub provides for an additional fee).

Comment: @jeffbyrnes We have dev, staging, prod, and few other branches. The commits in the dev branch are way ahead of prod branches and I would like to know will rebasing the history would affect them.
Also, the development team likes to have a git history of 3-6 months with tracking. Is it possible if I rebase it?

Comment: Multiple branches like that kinda make a rebase a nonstarter. Unfortunately, by including all that binary data, you may have boxed yourself into a corner :(

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way I can reduce my git history. There is a pack-xx.pack within .git>objects>pack of size 4.5GB I believe it retains the git history and tracking. 
The dev team likes to retain at least 3 months of history. I would like to know is there a way I can retain the last few month's histories and track and delete the rest to reduce its size.